# perl my variable $x masks earlier declaration in same statement

Tags: perl

I am confused on this error, this program takes user input 1 2 3 2 and displays the input in a *specific order*.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter a number :";

my $num = <STDIN>;
chomp($num);

my @final = split(' ',$num);
my @count;
foreach my $x (@final){

 $count[my $x]++;

}
foreach my $x (@count){

print my $x .$count[my $x];
}
```

my output : I get this error 
**"my" variable $x masks earlier declaration in same statement at line 19**

Expected output:

- 1 1
- 2 2
- 3 1

Comment: `my` is used to _define_ a variable. Do this only once. When you _use_ it you don't need the `my`. Simply write `$count[$x]++;`.

Comment: @PerlDuck: I'd say "declare" rather than "define", but yes.

Comment: "`my` creates a new variable"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `my` a little bit too often.

`my` is used to declare a variable, for the current scope (usually a block `{...}`).

To *use* the variable, you don't need the `my`.

So, in your first loop, do:

```
$count[ $x ]++;
```

In the second loop:

```
print "$x: $count[ $x ]\n";
```

See [perldoc -f my](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) and [Private-Variables-via-my](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my())

Comment: Thanks, I was messing around trying something different, those links helped a lot.